# Magento 2 - Category list query

Tags: category, magento2

I've got a module in magento 1 - it stops certain products being listed depending upon a set of attributes.

For example if the user logs in and an customer attribute set with a value of 100, they would see all products with an attribute called "test" with the value of 100 and no others...

I'm looking at porting this functionality accross to magento 2, I was hoping for some pointers on where magento 2 does the category listing...

In magento 1 I extend the mage/catalog/model/category and add an addattributetofilter... along with a few others things...

Looking breifly at magento 2, I thought that I'd be able to duplicate the behaviour by overwriting/extending CollectionFilter in the namespace 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category' yet anything I do here results in no results regardless of what I do.

Any tips/help would be great at the minute.

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to avoid overwriting/extending core classes because this introduces conflicts between extensions. You can add custom filter to product collection by adding observer on `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event.

Declare your observer, create `MyModule/etc/frontend/events.xml` with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_before">
        <observer name="add-filter-to-product-collection-observer" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\AddFilterToProductCollectionObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer `MyModule\Observer\AddFilterToProductCollectionObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class AddStockStatusToCollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Add filter to product collection
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute', 'value');
    }
}
```

Hope this will lead you in right direction.

Comment: not tested it yet. But that looks spot on.

Comment: it works fine but a problem with pagination, pagination showing wrong count and same for layer navigation.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Thats all great but there doesn't seem to be a catalog_product_collection_load_before was removed from changelog Removed some events (plugins must be used instead):

Comment: I've wrote a plugin, but am a little unsure where magento 2 actually gets the product collection for the category, any pointers for this would be apprichiated atm.

Comment: Also as user3383912 says - it always shows the wrong count.

Comment: catalog_product_collection_load_before was removed form magento 2

Comment: Using events and observers for this will not work. As others have mentioned. The counts and pagination will break. The original poster was closer to the actual solution as far as I can tell. Overriding prepareProductCollection  in Search.php with custom query works great for free text searching but overriding prepareProductCollection in Category.php makes category blank as stated. I still haven't found the cause of this, but I do know Observers and events cause more problems, they do not fix this situation.